# Quantos bytes tem um decimal(18,8)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como calculo a quantidade de bytes de um decimal? No meu caso decimal(18,8).

Por que decimal(18,8)? 
R: Porque vou guardar valores exatos para bitcoin no meu BD

Recomenda maneira melhor que decimal(18,8)?

Comment: Qual o contexto da sua pergunta? Por que precisa saber disto? Quer saber no âmbito do C# ou do SQL Server? Como podemos dizer porque usar `decimal(18,8)` se você que está usando não sabe? O que de fato importa nisso?

Comment: Porque sou curioso e quero saber quanto ocupa na memoria.

Comment: Tem 8 bytes....

Comment: Segundo a documentação da Microsoft para o SQL Server: 9 bytes. [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017]

Comment: Agradeço anonimo, vlw!